# Extract data from panda where the column has recently changed for about to change

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda data frame with a column  `num` that ranges from 1 to 48.

I want to extract all rows where the `num` column is different to its previous value or it is about to change value

How would I go about doing so?

the data frame looks like this:

```
num    x 
1     25
1     26
1     22
1     35
.     .
.     .
.     .
48    25
48    31
48    32
48    27
```

It has over 9,000 rows

so the output data frame would just be

```
num x 
1    38
1    34
2    39
2    25
3    26
3    30
4    45
4    39
.    .
.    .
.    .
```

Comment: What do you mean by change is about to happen? Do you mean where the column `num` changes value?

Comment: I don't understand you'r question.. Please write it again and give expected output

Comment: Do you mean extracting rows that `num` and `x` differ by +/- 10 points?

Comment: What do you mean with "extract all columns". You mean rows?

Comment: if you mean extracting rows before and after num changes (you just want to see the transitions `df[(df['num'] != df['num'].shift(1)) | (df['num'] != df['num'].shift(-1))]`

Comment: @KenSyme how would I increase the shift include up to 30 rows without having 30 lines of the code

Comment: Jut change the 1 and -1 to 30 and -30 - it just literally shifts the dataframe by that many rows up or down to do the comparison